# Delaying ajax upload until a user hits a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use [this plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/), and I don't see a way to easily enable auto-upload.

I've been playing around for a bit, but I still don't have a good solution. Does anyone see how I would prevent auto-upload and trigger the upload on some other action?

Comment: You can just use a different plugin, like:  http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin I use, that doesn't require flash (got the plugin from): http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxFileUpload

**And you can call it with:**

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
        url:file_uppload_url_here,
        secureuri:false,
        fileElementId: file_element_id_here,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status)
        {

        },
        send: function(data)
        {
        },
        error: function (data, status, e)
        {
            console.debug(data);
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Seems similar to what I need, but I'd rather go with a more supported plugin. Also, you realize you just transferred your work into the Creative Commons, aye?

Comment: Not sure what that means, but this is where I got it:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxFileUpload  Couldn't find the link when I posted - edited my post

Comment: Ack. I need the "extra unwanted form fields." :P

Comment: I just passed the val() of my required fields in the upload_url_here area.  Worked pretty well.

Comment: I'd still rather use the other plugin. It's also giving me drag and drop and cancellability. I'll keep looking at modification

Answer (score -1):

Since this is plugin specific, your best bet is to look at the source code on its [github](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) repo and override the drag-and-drop event.

It also looks like it is possible to override the onSubmit functionality through options but I assume you've already tried that.

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    // path to server-side upload script
     action: '/server/upload',

    // events         
    // you can return false to abort submit
    onSubmit: function( id, filename ){
       // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: I can abort the submit, but then how do I upload the files? input.files is null, and I can no longer pass in the input to any of the library methods.